# Trying to fetch data for a Youtube video with the v3 API returns CORS

Tags: angular, typescript, cors, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to fetch data on a video using the V3 youtube data API using Angular, I have an account, set up a project, added the API and got an API key. all is set in the google developers site includng the right restritctions.
but when im trying to send out a simple HTTP get call I'm getting CORS.
the call is:

```
 this.http.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=kd1u1ZdJz4w&key=mykey&fields=items(snippet(title))&part=snippet')
            .subscribe(res => {
              console.log(res);
            });
```

getting the error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=kd1u1ZdJz4w&key=myket&fields=items(snippet(title))&part=snippet'
> from origin 'mydomain' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which
> must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The
> credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is
> controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

when navigating to the API link direcrtly from the browser I get a successful JSON response.

any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

To answer my own question,
in my case it was because I sent an Authorization header and it didnt go well with the API's response, so I excluded the url from getting the Authorization Token, plus added a { withCredentials: false } parameter to the options object in the http.get() function.
works great.